# Migrating a SQL Anywhere database using triggers

Tags: triggers, migration, export, sqlanywhere

I was trying to create a trigger using SQL Anywhere which would export the database so it can be transferred to another database. The query is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Estudante ;
OUTPUT TO 'c:\Users\XUSERX\Desktop\file.xml' 
    QUOTE '"'
    FORMAT XML ;
```

When running it shows error on the line

```
OUTPUT TO 'c:\Users\XUSERX\Desktop\file.xml'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `OUTPUT TO` syntax is only available in the dbisql utility, not in stored procedures or triggers. Look at the `UNLOAD` statement in the [docs](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbreference/unload-statement.html*d5e70301).

*Disclosure: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*